# Blood oxygen level spo2 sensor

Tags: android, kotlin, sensors, watch, google-fit

I am currently developing an Android application to my samsung wear Galaxy 4. I want to access and measure blood oxygen level and I would like display my watch screen.

Unfortunately, I didn't find the sensor when I was looking for in the references
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview
Have you any idea how to access and display in my watch?

Comment: It looks like you need to use the Google Fit API.
Docs are here: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors

Comment: @Fodor Balázs, Did you find a solution?