# Oxygen saturation measurement API for Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 (Wear OS)

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-mobile, samsung-health, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

- tried to use Samsung Health SDK, but it doesn't work on watch
- <s>also, Android Health Services don't work on real device</s>
- Google fit API does not suit me (the comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975754/android-blood-oxygen-level-spo2-sensor))

any other oxygen saturation API for Wear OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>For a while, oxygen saturation measurement API is not supported on Galaxy Watch 4 *(answered by Samsung Developers team on 5 October 2021)*</s>

Oxygen saturation measurement API is available in Samsung Privileged Health SDK *(answered by Samsung Developers team on 30 March 2022)*